Is $S_\infty:=\{f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N \text{ is a bijection}\}$ of first category in itself?
Is $S_\infty:=\{f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N \text{ is a bijection}\}$ of first category (in itself)?
Regard $S_\infty$ as the subset of $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$. The toplogy on $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$ is the usual topology induced by the metric $d(f,g)=\frac1{n+1},$ where $f(k)=g(k), \forall k \le n-1$ and $f(n)\ne g(n)$.
Edit:
I have only proved that $S_\infty$ is a $G_\delta$ set. I tried to write $S_\infty$ into a countable union of nowhere dense sets, but I didn't have a good idea. So I guess that $S_\infty$ is not of first category in itself. I just began learning functional analysis and I do not know much about how to prove or refute this.
I am asking this question because I am trying to work out this question, which I have mentioned before in another question:

Let $(a_n)$ be a series that is convergent but not absolutely convergent. Prove that
$$M = \{\sigma \in S_\infty : (a_{\sigma(n)})\text{ converges}\}$$
is a set of first category in $S_\infty$.

I thought that $\overline M=S_\infty$, but this seems not true.

$S_\infty$ is Polish, because it is a $G_\delta$ subset of $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$, hence it is a Baire space, and therefore it is not meager (i.e. of first category) in itself.
If you were asking about whether $S_\infty$ is meager as a subset of $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$, the answer to that is yes. For suppose $S_\infty$ were non-meager. Since it has the Baire Property, by localization it would have to be comeager in some basic open set $N_s$ of $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$, where $s$ is a partial injection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$. In particular, $S_\infty \cap N_s$ would be dense in $N_s$. But this is false, because $S_\infty$ is disjoint from the non-empty open set $N_{t}$ whenever $t\supset s$ is a finite partial function extending $s$ that is not injective.
